# Change background image of PictureBox on mouseover in C#?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, picturebox

How can I change the background image of a PicureBox when I hover my mouse over it in C#?
I'm using visual c# 2010 Express.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You just need to subscribe to MouseHover Event an change Image Property.

This should do the trick:

```
PictureBox o = new PictureBox();
o.MouseHover += (a_sender, a_args) =>
{
    PictureBox pic = a_sender as PicureBox;
    pic.Image = null // New Image..
};
```

Again when you need to restore previous picture use: `MouseLeave`

Answer (score 1):

On PictureBox properties, double click on event MouseEnter and use:

```
(sender as PictureBox).Image = Image.FromFile(// path of image1);
```

then double click on event MouseLeave and use:

```
(sender as PictureBox).Image = Image.FromFile(// path of image2);
```